# TypeScript - Determine allowed array values from multiple arrays in object

Tags: typescript

I have object with multiple arrays of strings (hardcoded). In other empty array I want to specify that only strings from that object are allowed.

In simple not nested I'm doing this with
`typeof someArray[number][]` so I hoped that with nested array this will work `typeof someObjectWithArrays[string][number][]` but no :/

I thing this example will explain better what I mean:

```
const demo1 = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'] as const
const demo2 = {
  a: ['test4', 'test5', 'test6'],
  b: ['test7', 'test8', 'test9'],
} as const

const values = {
  demo1: [] as typeof demo1[number][], // allow 'test1' 'test2' 'test3'
  demo2: [] as typeof demo2[string][number][], // ????? allow 'test4' 'test5' 'test6' 'test7' 'test8' 'test9'
}

console.log(values.demo1.includes('test1')) // ok
console.log(values.demo1.includes('notexists')) // error, so ok

console.log(values.demo2.includes('test8')) // ????? should be ok
console.log(values.demo2.includes('notexists')) // ????? should be error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=16&pln=9&pc=46#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwLYgIwwLwwNoHIoLSq4A0M%20hUATKeQdAMy4C6MAhhDKJFAFDfR4yEFUwwA3rxjsAXDgrQALLQVQArCvpQAbCxJSYAIzl4tAdk2UAHJegBOPbwC%207TgL79wggG5sANgCuhGKS0ogoqCasHDBQAJ4ADgggAGZCEdhgAUiGCABOzNjMZAD0Jex%20fiAA7nSUxHXQNI1QTAbhIlGusYnJaR1U2NB5AJZgAOaFWTn5hcUwZTAA-CsrFVW1qsotGi26LRYtNi0OzryekCB%20CAB0VeMAFL6BhDcdqDdjwIGIEA%20qxAAlICFuUQABrC4QK63e5PfxBCBvYQfL4-Qj-MAgAgADxG0AguGBoJg%20TyIDyZGhMAh5wEMLuIEez0RyJQVE%20YG%20AV%20-y0NmJi1WawgAAsQAE-HAjAgaZD6ddGcyEa8BpzubzcFjcfioITBeVhUsYGKJVKZaS8uS8ucgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the index of `typeof demo2` to be `keyof typeof demo2`:

```
const demo1 = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'] as const
const demo2 = {
  a: ['test4', 'test5', 'test6'],
  b: ['test7', 'test8', 'test9'],
} as const

const values = {
  demo1: [] as typeof demo1[number][],
  demo2: [] as typeof demo2[keyof typeof demo2][number][],
}

console.log(values.demo1.includes('test1')) // ok
console.log(values.demo1.includes('notexists')) // error, so ok

console.log(values.demo2.includes('test8')) // correctly ok
console.log(values.demo2.includes('notexists')) // correctly errors
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgUwLYgIwwLwwNoHIoLSq4A0M+hUATKeQdAMy4C6MAhhDKJFALABQ3aPGQgqmGAG8BMdgC4cFaABZaSqAFY19KADYWJGTABGCvDoDs2ygA5r0AJwGBAX3achffgM8wAbmwANgCuhBLS-LKIKKhmrBwwUACeAA4IIABmIjHYYMFIxggATszYzIaR2WJx7omp6VnRYtgA1ghJmXVpnU1UpXkFxaXlrgI+4BAggQgAdIEgAOYAFAEhhDNNqDMAlmDAIYgQS+rEAJSnMAD0lzAgLeOQU7Pzy6uhEBuiW7v7wYfHYBABAAHttoBBcOcrjdikUQEUyJNbvdvIIJk85osVkF3p8UFQdnsDoRjjo7FDrlx4UUEMAoIEksiHpNppjXjj1r1Cb9-rhASCwVAIRSbqAijS6QyYLD4RABEA)